# Speex decoder doesn't produce expected result

Tags: javascript, java, speex

I have encrypted data from JAVA j-speex

I am trying to decode this data using the speex decoder in JavaScript.

Most of data is giving -2 and -1 and very few data is giving correct decoded data.

I am getting some sound with noise. It is not as clear as I expect.

Comment: show the code you've got so we can correct it - don't expect someone to write it all for you :p

Comment: var spx = new Speex({
                    rate: 16000,
                    //size: 8,
                    quality: 8,
                    mode: 1
                    //lpcm: false
                }
                );

Comment: thanks for response me.
I got the actual sound after changing the Speex configuration.

                var spx = new Speex({
                    quality: 7,
                    mode: 1,
                    bits_size: 70,
                    lpcm: false
                }
                );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Befor 
               var spx = new Speex({
                    rate: 16000,
                    size: 16,
                    quality: 6,
                    mode: 0
                    //lpcm: false
                }
                );
It  is gives lot of -2(corrupted stream),-1(Invalid Stream) and very few 
correct decoded data.
When i change into the Speex parameter its giving proper decoded data.
 After changing the Speex Setting:
              var spx = new Speex({
                    quality: 7,
                    mode: 1,
                    bits_size: 70,
                    lpcm: false
                }
                );

Thanks,